# How did the orchids evolve to support pseudocopulation when they do not have any organ for vision to see how insects look like?

Tags: evolution, botany, entomology, reproduction

How could they guess so perfectly how a moth or whatever the pseudocopulating organism looks like. They do not have eyes to see the shape or structure. What could possibly be the reason they evolved with such accuracy to deceive an animal?

Comment: plants don't consciously control their shape why would they need eyes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Evolution does not work based on an organism (or designer) "seeing" a problem and seeking a solution. Evolution via natural selection works when members of a population that have a certain heritable trait are better at reproducing than other members of that population. Because they are better at reproducing, subsequent generations of the population have a greater percentage of individuals that have that heritable trait, and the process continues, sometimes to the extent that all the individuals of that species have that trait (this is called "fixation").

The way something like this would evolve is that some predecessor to modern orchids has some morphology or chemical secretion that was particularly attractive to insects. This increased the ability of that predecessor to reproduce. Over generations, any other random mutations that further promoted attraction of insects also were selected for, until they accumulated all of the adaptations we see in a modern orchid.

Today, we can study that process and realize post facto that "Oh, these adaptations worked because they tricked the insects into thinking they were copulating, when really they were just dispersing pollen."

However, the flower never needed any knowledge of insect copulation, it just happened that flowers that had those traits did better at propagating their genes to the next generation.

These types of questions are more easily understood with a broad understanding of evolution. One great resource is [Understanding Evolution](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/home.php) from Berkeley.